# The method join(String[], char) is undefined for the type

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium. I got the error

> The method join(String[], char) is undefined for the type

while working on Selenium Server in Eclipse.  I am wondering what the equivalent of the `join` command is in Selenium. Or should I use a jar file to handle this error?

---

I am exploring Selenium RC where I copied JUnit code from IDE into Eclipse and trying to debug the errors. I added couple of jar files and replaced `VerifyTrue` with `assertTrue` for a similar error. But I don't know what to replace the `join` command with. Here is the code snippet:

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
    try {
        if ("".equals(join(selenium.getAllFields(), ','))) break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: For *which* type? What are you trying to achieve? Why did you expect it to work?

Comment: could we see some code, please?

Comment: I am exploring Selenium RC where I copied junit code from IDE into Eclipse and trying to debug the errors. I added couple of jar files and replaced 'VerifyTrue' with 'assertTrue' for a similar error. But dont know what to replace 'join' command with. Here is the code snippet:                                                             for (int second = 0;; second++) {
   if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
   try { if ("".equals(join(selenium.getAllFields(), ','))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
   Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: @kshali I added your last comment to your question for clarity and to be actually able to read the code. Next time, feel free to use the `Edit` button :).

Comment: @Slanec thanks. sure will use Edit..

Answer (score 1):

[Apache commons-lang library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//) has the [`StringUtils.join()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20char%29) method that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried to add the commons-lang library jar file.. but am still not able to resolve the issue...

Comment: You need to put the imminent-lang jar in your classpath, and add an import statement to your class for the StringUtils class